# How can I test whether jmx-console.war is being used in JBoss 4.2.2?

Tags: security, jboss, console, jmx, nessus

There is a file within the .\jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\default\deploy folder, named "jmx-console.war".  I am getting a security vulnerability dealing with this module.  How can I tell if our application is using this module.  I implemented an open source tool, but I'm not sure how to test whether it's being used.

**Nessus vulnerability of High Severity:**

***JBoss JMX Console Unrestricted Access***

http://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=23842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see that war file in the deploy folder, then most likely your application is using it. That is to say, it is most likely being loaded. It should be fairly easy to test for, assuming you know the HTTP port the JBoss instance is listening on. By default, it is **8080** so point your browser to **http://[your jboss host]:8080/jmx-console** and see if the console comes up, keeping in mind that it might be password protected, and your HTTP port might not be 8080.

You should also see something like this in the **server.log** or configured equivalent:

> 11:52:30,165 INFO  main [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/jmx-console,
>   warUrl=.../deploy/jmx-console.war/

Having said that, there's a couple of ways I can think of that would indicate or cause the jmx-console to not be deployed:

- The folder you referenced is in the **default** server directory. This is only one instance out of 3 (default, all, minimal) and you may be running one of the others, or even a custom configured server. That is to say, if you were running the **minimal** server instance, or one that did not contain the jmx-console.war, then the presence of that file in the default server's deploy directory would not cause it to be deployed in another server's instance.  (that all sounds more complicated than it really is)
- War files in the deploy directory depend on *another* directory called **jboss-web.deployer** which actually deploys war files. If that directory is not there, my guess is that war deployment has been disabled. Highly unlikely though, as there are easier ways of doing this, and if someone went to the trouble of removing this folder, they probably would have removed the wars too.

Bottom line is, the easiest way would be to find the http port, then hit the jmx-console URL and see if it responds, or check the log file. It is *conceivable* that someone could rename jmx-console.war to something else (in an ill-conceived attempt to hide it perhaps ?) in which case, you would need to execute a battery of http request scans and try and find a jmx-console signature, but that's out of my (otherwise quite large...) area of expertise.

Comment: two things... (1) I couldn't get to this address on the box running JBoss: "http://localhost:8080/jmx-console" (2) Found something interesting.  I was still able to run my application without issues when I removed this entire folder: .\jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\default\deploy\jmx-console.war\